# Avoiding repeating code in swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics, redundancy

In following code, based on the string comparison I am deciding on which VC will be shown.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    dataObj = frc.object(at: indexPath) as! Data_Object
    var pvc: UIViewController?

    if dataObj.type == "X" {

        let obj = MainStoryboard().instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "XVC") as! XVC
        obj.data = dataObj
        obj.isFull = true
        obj.delegate = self
        pvc = obj as UIViewController

    } else if dataObj.type == "Y" {

        let obj = MainStoryboard().instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YVC") as! YVC
        obj.data = dataObj
        obj.isFull = true
        obj.delegate = self
        pvc = obj as UIViewController

    } else {

        let obj = MainStoryboard().instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ZVC") as! ZVC
        obj.data = dataObj
        obj.isFull = true
        obj.delegate = self
        pvc = obj as UIViewController
    }

    obj.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    let popPVC = pvc?.popoverPresentationController
    popPVC?.sourceView = self.view
    self.present(pvc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now, all of the code is repetitive except class name and I want to avoid that. But, swift do not have `NSClassFromString`

How do I accomplish this? Should I use Generics/Templates? Any suggestions!

Sorry in advance, if I am missing something silly here.

Comment: Yes you can create simple function for accomplish this String(describing: SomeViewController.self)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The removal of duplication is obvious:

```
let identifier: String

switch dataObj.type {
    case "X":
       identifier = "XVC"
    case "Y":
       identifier = "YVC"
    default:
       identifier = "ZVC"
}

let pvc = MainStoryboard().instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as! PVC
pvc.data = dataObj
pvc.isFull = true
pvc.delegate = self
```

Where `PVC` is the common superclass of your 3 controllers, e.g. :

```
class PVC : UIViewController {}
class XVC : PVC {}
class YVC : PVC {}
class ZVC : PVC {}
```

If your 3 classes don't have a common superclass, you can use a protocol instead:

```
protocol PVC : class {
   var data: ...
   var isFul: ...
   weak var delegate: ...
}
```

and implement it by your 3 classes:

In short, to remove the duplication, you need to add a common interface to the 3 controllers. Either using a common superclass or protocol.

Comment: Thank You for your time. It helped me a lot. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

I prefer Sulthan's answer since it's cleaner that mine (Have to admit...)

To complete mine, `getControllerFor:type` need to return a parent class. Forgot to mention it

I edited First answer to correct several misses and to make it more concise

**First answer**

You could do something like that :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

  dataObj = frc.object(at: indexPath) as! Data_Object
  var pvc: UIViewController?

  let obj = getControllerFor(type: dateObj.type)
  obj.data = dataObj
  obj.isFull = true
  obj.delegate = self
  pvc = obj as UIViewController
  obj.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
  let popPVC = pvc?.popoverPresentationController
  popPVC?.sourceView = self.view
  self.present(pvc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}



func getControllerFor(type : String) -> SuperType? {
  switch type {
  case "X": return XVC()
  case "Y": return YVC()
  case "Z": return ZVC()
  default: return nil
  }
}
```

with

```
class SuperType {}
class XVC: SuperType {}
class YVC: SuperType {}
class ZVC: SuperType {}
```

Ideally, `type` isn't a `String` but an `Enum`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this nicely with an enum. You just need to get each of your ViewControllers to conform to CustomViewController.

```
enum ViewControllers: String {
    case x = "X"
    case y = "Y"
    case z = "Z"

    func getViewController<T>(dataObj: Data_Object, delegate: YourDelegate?) -> T where T: UIViewController, T: CustomViewController {
        let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: self.rawValue) as! T
        viewController.data = dataObj
        viewController.isFull = true
        viewController.delegate = delegate

        return viewController
    }
}

protocol CustomViewController: class {
    var data: Data_Object! { get set }
    var isFull: Bool! { get set }
    weak var delegate: YourDelegate? { get set }
}
```

You would then use it like this:

```
if dataObj.type == "X" {
     let vc: XVC = ViewControllers.x.getViewController(dataObj: dataObj, delegate: self)
    pvc = vc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a function that get the identifier and return the viewcontroller. Since your XVC, YVC, ZVC does have similarity, you can also make them subclassed of other VC that have their property like `data, isFull,...`

Also, you can use similar to `NSClassFromString` with `String(describing: SomeViewController.self)` will return `SomeViewController`